# Satmar and head covering

Tags: women, chasidut-hasidism, hair-covering, satmar

I was looking pictures of the Satmar wedding and I found that some women where wearing a headscarf with no hair out and others where wearing a wig or a wig with a scarf.

Why is that ? What is the official rule for Satmar ?

Comment: When are these pictures from? It could be hair covering styles in Satmar have changed over time.

Comment: In the background: http://news.xinhuanet.com/english/photo/2013-01/24/132125789_11n.jpg

Comment: Why can't it be that they can wear anything that covers their hair, just like other religious married women?

Comment: As far as I know, Satmar women use a headscarf and no hair out because Satmar is not like other religious communities. No communities is like another. All have their own mesorah. This is why I ask.

Comment: Might I recommend you [edit] that motivation in to your question?

Comment: No problem but what do you want me to edit exactly ?

Answer (score 9):

Satmar frowns upon wearing a wig only. Besides for that, each woman (family, husband...) decides. In fact Satmar is one of the least uniformly dressed chassidic groups, both among men, and among women. The most common mode is a wig with something on top, like a band, a hat, or a scarf. However, some will wear a shpitzel (cloth or foam in the general shape of hair – think animated movie), or only a scarf. At home, many will wear a turban, which is always worn without a wig. The hair will never stick out, as the [Hungarian custom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31969/3073) is to shave the head after marriage.

The rule (which stems from Grand Rabbi Joel Teitelbaum's opposition to wigs) is only enforced in places where Satmar is in complete control, mainly in Kiryas Joel, NY, and then only for residents, and not for visitors.

Source: Experience living in the Satmar communities of London, Monsey, Kiryas Joel, and Montreal. My wife's family is Satmar too.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yashar coach for this complete answer. I have seen a lot of shpitzel in Satmar communities. Is it Rabbi Yoel Teitelbaum rule (to wear a shpitzel instead of a wig with something on top) ? Do the shpitzel include some fake hair ? Are they always made with foam inside to imitate the hair ?

Comment: @ari Go ahead and ask a new question: "What are the different types of Shpitzlach (pl. of Spitzel)? Who recommends..."

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34544/what-are-the-different-types-of-shpitzlach