# What are the different types of Shpitzlach?

Tags: minhag, hair-covering

Do [shpitzels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shpitzel) include some fake hair ? Are they always made with foam inside to imitate the hair?

Answer (score 3):

Spitzlach may include fake hair, and may have foam, but many do not. There are basically three types, all of which are worn between the forehead and the headscarf:

1. A hard edge covered with short strands of fake hair giving a look of hair that loops around and is tucked in under the scarf. (This should not be confused with a "fall" which is a piece consisting of the frontal locks only of a sheitel, hanging loose from the scarf over the forehead. A "fall" looks like a sheitel where everything but the front was tucked in under the scarf.)
2. A cloth covered foam block simulating the appearance of the above, but with cloth instead of parallel hair strands. It often includes the shape of a parting.
3. A lace lying flat on the forehead, where the strands of lace simulate loops of hair.

**Warning:** Photos of women wearing type 1 and 3 are revealed by hovering over the area below.

> [image: Type 1][image: Type 3]

Comment: Thanks ! So there is always something faking something else. Foam, fake hair, or lace.

Comment: @ari That doesn't distinguish it from a wig (sheitel) or a "fall" (frontal locks of a sheitel). Should I edit in the difference between a "fall" and a type-1 spitzel?

Comment: It would be great. What is exactely a "fall" ?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Do you know a hair covering type which does not fake hair ?

Comment: You could [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)... There are snoods, various types of scarves, hats...

Comment: thanks ;) http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35370/do-you-know-a-hair-covering-type-which-does-not-fake-hair

Comment: the other question has been deleted. can you please list them here ?