# Do women have to have long hair according to Jewish law?

Tags: halacha, minhag, women, oral-torah

Does it say anywhere in the Oral Torah that women have to have long hair?

Comment: See Eruvin 100b

Comment: Also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31969/759

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Jake and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @DoubleAA Answer?

Comment: Kaballically in short: hair=Dinim, woman=Dinim, Dinim=Binah man=Chessed=Chochmah, etc. Therefore (traditionally): women [*are expected to*] shave everything from the ears downward while men shave from the ears upward and leave everything else. As King Solomon was shocked seeing the queen of Sheba not shaving her legs and said: "שער יפה לאנשים ודופי לנשים" (Targum on Ester).

Comment: It's mashma from the gemara in Talmud Yerushalmi shabbas 6:1 (daf 34a) that Rochel- Rabbi Akivas wife would sell her locks of hair to support her husband in Torah learning.

Comment: @samsamsams so?