# Can a husband or father object to a woman becoming a Nazir

Tags: halacha, women, nedarim-shevuot, nozir

According to Halacha, a husband or a father have a right to object to their wife or daughter (if their daughter is still under their father’s authority) taking a vow. My question is, does this apply to them becoming a Nazirite as well?

Comment: See my answer here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31969/minhag-of-married-women-shaving-during-marriage/32003#32003

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ramba'm codifies this in nezirus (2:17):

> נשים עובדים יש להם נזירות והאב או הבעל מפר נזירות האשה אם רצה כשאר הנדרים
>
> A woman and a slave can be nazirites, and a father or husband can nullify a woman's Naziriteship if he wants to, like other vows.

The Kesef Mishnah there brings the mishna in Nazir (62b) as the Rambam's source. The mishna says:

> חומר העבדים מבנשים שהוא מפר נדרי אשתו ואינו מפר נדרי עבדו
>
> The previous Mishna taught that the naziriteship of women includes a stringency that does not apply to slaves. This mishna adds: There is a greater stringency in the case of slaves then in the case of women, as a man can nullify the vows of his wife but he cannot nullify the vows of his slave. (Sefaria translation)

---

Credit to shmosel for the source

Comment: Indeed, you can add that Kesef Mishnah there points to the Mishnah on Nazir 62b as the Rambam's source. https://www.sefaria.org/Nazir.62b.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en